# How to make the default radio button to be unchecked while using Razor in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button, razorengine

I am using radio button like this,

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.gender)
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.gender, "Male")
                        Male
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.gender, "Female")
                        Female
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

here i have two radio button which is rendered in the page, i want the radio button to be rendered and without the default selection of any of the radio button, how can i do this

i tried like this but it is not working

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.gender, "Female", new { @checked = "true" })
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class student
    {             
        [DisplayName("Gender")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "please select gender")]
        public gender gender { get; set; }
    } 

public enum gender
    {
        male,
        female
    }
```

Comment: What type is "x.gender" property of your model?

Comment: hi, please see the updated question, thakn you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make sure nothing is selected by default, make your property nullable:

```
public gender? gender { get; set; }
```

Its default value will be `null`, and that will make sure nothing is selected, but `Required` attribute won't allow `null` as valid value once user posted the form.

On a separate note, you are using strings as values right now, I am not sure that is going to work with enum at all. It would be much better to do something along these lines:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.gender, gender.Female)
@Html.Label(gender.Female.ToString())
// Or you can stick to literals for labels as you do now.
// This however allows you to eventually turn this rendering code into a loop
```

Comment: when i do that, i get an error like this,
The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type

Comment: on the .cshtml page

Comment: @LijinJohn, sure. "where" usually means "on which line"

Comment: Note that `@Html.Label(gender.Female.ToString())` will not create a label associated with the button - clicking on it will not set focus, and should use `new { id = "" }` to remove duplicate `id` attributes in radio buttons

Comment: @StephenMuecke, that's a good point, thanks. I am not sure how to fix the first association thing though - any ideas?

Comment: @Andrei, I tend to use `<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.gender, gender.Female)<span>@gender.Female</span></label>`. Alternatively you need something like `@Html.Label("", gender.Female.ToString(), new { for = gender.Female })` and add `new { id = gender.Female }` to the radio button (its just unfortunate issue with the `RadioButtonFor()` method generating duplicate `id` attributes)

Comment: BTW, OP's use of a string does work, but using the `enum` value is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.gender, "Female")
```